# Sum a rows within a column for each unique combination r

Tags: r

I'd like to sum a value in a given column for each unique combination of two other columns:

For example I'd like to transform the following dataframe from:

```
Week  Day  Value
1     1    1
1     2    3
1     3    4
2     1    2
2     2    2
2     3    3
```

to:

```
Week  Day  Value Sum
1     1    1     1
1     2    3     4
1     3    4     8
2     1    2     2
2     2    2     4
2     3    3     7
```

I think a `for` loop would do what I want - but I am completely lost at this point - any and all help appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest to try `dplyr`. Quite a workhorse in data manipulation. From the desired output, you seem to try to get cumulative sum based on Week.

```
df = read.table(text="Week  Day  Value
1     1    1
1     2    3
1     3    4
2     1    2
2     2    2
2     3    3", header=T)

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Week) %>% mutate(Sum = cumsum(Value))

# you get
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: Week

  Week Day Value Sum
1    1   1     1   1
2    1   2     3   4
3    1   3     4   8
4    2   1     2   2
5    2   2     2   4
6    2   3     3   7
```

Or you could try `data.table`, another tool which is great for data of larger size. Fast and memory efficient.

```
setDT(df)[, Sum := cumsum(Value), by = Week][]
   Week Day Value Sum
1:    1   1     1   1
2:    1   2     3   4
3:    1   3     4   8
4:    2   1     2   2
5:    2   2     2   4
6:    2   3     3   7
```

Comment: This worked liked a charm - didn't know about the cumsum  function of dplyr - very convenient!!

Comment: `cumsum` is from base R.

Answer (score 4):

In base R, you can use `ave()`:

```
x <- read.table(header=T, text="
Week  Day  Value
1     1    1
1     2    3
1     3    4
2     1    2
2     2    2
2     3    3
")
x$Sum <- ave(x$Value, x$Week, FUN=cumsum)

> x
  Week Day Value Sum
1    1   1     1   1
2    1   2     3   4
3    1   3     4   8
4    2   1     2   2
5    2   2     2   4
6    2   3     3   7
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for loops are probably a bad way of looking at this - they're not very efficient on data frames. Instead I'd recommend [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/):

```
#Turn into a data.table.
dt <- data.table(df)

#Sum, for each unique combination
dt <- dt[, j = list(value_sum = sum(Value)), by = c("Week","Day")]
```

Your actual example seems to just sum for each unique *week*, in which case, drop "Day" from "by".

Comment: This is not what the Q is looking for. If we look at the last column of the desired output, it's the cumulative sum of Value based on Week.

Comment: ...yes? See "your actual example seems to just sum for each unique week, in which case, drop "Day" from "by"". While the example only uses one variable, the question referred to unique combinations of two values, so I answered for both.

Comment: Please look again.  It's `cumsum`.  Did you check the result with your code? Suggest to paste the result to the answer if otherwise.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha; I see what you mean! Yep; misunderstood.